# How to save Object-Lists with ObjectOutputStream and how to read these in?

Tags: java, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I've a list with "group" objects:

```
protected static ArrayList<Gruppe> groups=new ArrayList<Gruppe>();
```

Now I want to save the whole list.

```
oos.writeObject(groups);
```

is this correct?
or save each separately?

like this:

```
for(Gruppe g:groups){
    oos.writeObject(g);//geht nicht..?
}
```

**And how to read it in?**
*ObjectInputStream*

```
groups=(ArrayList<Gruppe>) ois.readObject();
```

or seperatly again?

```
groups=new ArrayList<Gruppe>();

Gruppe k=null;
while ((k=(Gruppe) ois.readObject()) != null) {
    groups.add(k);
}
```

Header from *Gruppe*:

```
public class Gruppe extends JPanel implements Comparable<Gruppe>, Serializable{
```

Save:
StackTrace in first way

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.XPStyle
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.save(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at ralaProgramme.OccupancyOverview.fileSave(OccupancyOverview.java:542)
at ralaProgramme.OccupancyOverview.Action_menuBar(OccupancyOverview.java:298)
at ralaProgramme.OccupancyOverview.actionPerformed(OccupancyOverview.java:260)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the whole list at once. If you write each group seperately, you'll have to read them in a loop until you get an exception, or you'll have to send the number of groups before sending the groups themselves to know how many groups to read. Sending the list is much easier.

Comment: That's because you try to send objects the reference objects that are not serializable, as the exception message says. You should send *data* over the wire. Sending an object which references a swing look and feel is bad design.

Comment: ok, i reference system default look and feel; so I could only save things if I have a Java style?

Comment: No. You shouldn't serialize data referencing a look and feel at all. What's the point in serializing a look and feel? Serialize data. If the look and feel is really part of the data (i.e. you want the receiver to use the serialized look and feel), the serialize the class name of the look and feel.

Comment: if I remove the UIManager line from the main() method saving works; reading doesn't [nullpointer]. I've a serializable JPanel.... -> So I've to make to classes: one which shows the data and one which conatains it?
and I open the file with an editor: there ar gui components from the main programm, which aren't in the list...!?

Comment: Yes, you should have a class representing the data you want to send. When you send a document to a friend, you send the PDF or doc or HTML file. You don't send Adobe reader or MS Word or Firefox.

Comment: so I have to make a class which shows the data; I've a class with the data, but in an jpanel style

Comment: now it works! fine! thx :D some lines work more but it works ;)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot serialize Objects that are not Serializable. You most certainly shouldn't serialize UI Components. Make sure your `ArrayList` is `ArrayList<Serializable>` that way you will get a compiler error when you try to add an Object which is not Serializable to the List.

Comment: public class Gruppe extends JPanel implements Comparable<Gruppe>, Serializable{

is it correct?
I had that before...

Comment: No. Your `Gruppe`class is not the problem. The problem is `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.XPStyle` which not only, does not implement Serializable, but is inherently Serialization unfriendly.

Answer (score 0):

You should both save and load the entire ArrayList as a whole. So the first alternative is correct in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Both are valid approaches. However, the serialized data is not generally readable. That is, you can only deserialize it with an objectInputStream.

Personally I would favor a solution like XStream. It serializes Java objects to XML which can also be processed by other tools, or read by humans.

http://x-stream.github.io/

Simple tutorial: http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html

Comment: thx but see up, I get an error message...
I'll have a look at XStream & I'll try :)